# What is the correct "null" value for a CSS string variable?

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-variables

Using CSS variables, I know you can set them:

```
--transform: translateX(30px);
transform: var(--transform, translateY(100%));
//         ^ usage          ^ fallback value if none specified
```

With transforms, it is possible to chain methods – as well as use complex variables:

```
--transform: translateX(30px) rotate(-12deg);
transform: var(--transform) translateX(10px) rotate(15deg) scale(1.5);
```

Is there a way of ignoring the `--transform`  (but still follow all of the other instructions before and after it)? I've tried:

```
--transform: none
--transform: ""
```

But obviously they invalidate the declaration.

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  gap: 100px;
}

.block{
  --turn-amount: rotate(45deg) rotate(13deg);
  --scale-amount: 3;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  transform: var(--turn-amount) scale(var(--scale-amount));
}
.block-1{
  --turn-amount: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="block block-1">Grow and turn</div>
<div class="block block-2">Just grow</div>
```

I would like to write something like:

```
.block-1{
  --turn-amount: null;
}
```

But  at the moment the best I've come up with is just to declare a "nothingy" transform, i.e.

```
.block-1{
  --turn-amount: scale(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple space is enough:

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  gap: 100px;
}

.block{
  --turn-amount: rotate(45deg) rotate(13deg);
  --scale-amount: 3;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  transform: var(--turn-amount) scale(var(--scale-amount));
}
.block-1{
  --turn-amount: ;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block-1">Grow and turn</div>
<div class="block block-2">Just grow</div>
```

Or like below. Note the usage of comma with nothing after it:

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  gap: 100px;
}

.block{
  --scale-amount: 3;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  transform: var(--turn-amount,) scale(var(--scale-amount));
}
.block-2{
  --turn-amount: rotate(45deg) rotate(13deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="block block-1">Grow and turn</div>
<div class="block block-2">Just grow</div>
```

> Note: That is, var(--a,) is a valid function, specifying that if the --a custom property is invalid or missing, the var() should be replaced with nothing.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables)</sup>